# Why am I getting a nil value from a Ruby object's member, when it is not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, null, member

I want to get the value of a field (ScenarioID) in a Ruby ActivityChart object (chart).  Displaying the whole chart shows the value I want: 160.

The problem was chart.Scenario yielded the nil value.  This could be reproduced in two ways: 1) by referencing chart.Scenario in the program, or by printing chart.Scenario in the debugger.

The chart object:

```
#<ActivityChart
  id: 1,
  ChartName: "Pipe 304 Chart",
  OverrideStartTime: nil,
  OverrideStopTime: nil,
  UseStartTime: false,
  UseStopTime: false,
  UseRecentSeconds: false,
  created_at: "2020-02-21 17:39:13",
  updated_at: "2020-03-02 16:17:22",
  RecentSeconds: nil,
  UseConcentrationCal: false,
  PercentComplete: 100.0,
  ShowOnDashboard: false,
  ScenarioID: 160>
```

ScenarioID is obviously not nil, yet that is what I'm getting in the program, and here in the debugger:

```
(byebug) p chart.id
1
(byebug) p chart.PercentComplete
100.0
(byebug) p chart.ScenarioID
nil
```

I get correct values for the other members, only ScenarioID is returning nil.  Why is this happening?  (I've only been programming in Ruby for a week, so it may be an obvious error.)  Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the class ScenarioID appears in:

```
class ActivityChart < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :ScenarioID
    validates :ChartName, presence: true, allow_blank: false
    validates :ScenarioID, presence: true
    validate :oneAndOnlyOne

    def oneAndOnlyOne
        if self.UseRecentSeconds && self.RecentSeconds == nil
            errors.add(:RecentSeconds, 'can\'t be blank')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The object representation is generated by the object's `inspect` method. It might show other data than those returned by the object's methods. How does the source code for the `ScenarioID` method look like?

Comment: There isn't a ScenarioID method; ScenarioID is a field in a class.  I've added the class definition to the original question.

Comment: @Stefan: Thanks -- Your question had me looking at the code another way, allowing me to stumble onto the solution!

Comment: Is `ScenarioID` also present as column in your database? If it is, Rails will automatically create a getter and a setter for the attribute. By defining `attr_accessor :ScenarioID` you are overriding the default setter/getter with different behaviour. Is your problem solved if you remove the `attr_accessor` definition?

Comment: @3limin4t0r: FYI, It doesn't work without attr_accessor :ScenarioID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem:  chart.ScenarioID is the way I'd do it in C++ and it doesn't work here; it returns nil.

In Ruby, **chart[:ScenarioID]** works, and correctly returns 160.

Comment: Note that this isn't a language difference. It's just how this particular object / class works. You are calling two different methods: `Chart#ScenarioID` which returns `nil` and `Chart#[]` which returns `160` for the argument / key `:ScenarioID`. The former comes from `attr_accessor :ScenarioID` whereas the latter comes from `ApplicationRecord`. (which might also provide a `ScenarioID` method)